# Android 13 - getCurrentPosition - simple HTML

Tags: android

this simple HTML code attached at the bottom, runs on Windows 11/Android 8 with no issues.

on Android 13, I am unable to run it.

I get -

> ERROR(1): User denied Geolocation

the HTML file is located on the Galaxy S21 Internal storage and opened with Chrome.
I gave all permissions I know of, but no success.

I never got the prompt of "Allow access to your location".....

I am not an expert.
I would like to provide all the required permission in the HTML code itself, if possible.

**thank you very much**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
const options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  const crd = pos.coords;
  alert(`${crd.latitude} ${crd.longitude}`);
}

function error(err) {
  alert(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
}

function getLocation() {
    //alert("getLocation")
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        //alert("getLocation true")
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
     alert(position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude)
}
</script>
</head>
 <body>
<p>
 Click on the button to find your location.
</p>
<button onclick="javascript: getLocation();">Get my location</button>
<div id="demo">
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```